# how to create realtime notification in django without using django channels

Tags: django, django-notification

For every action such as-

- log in
- sign up
- password reset

Notifications should be seen to the user with a notification bell icon (just like Facebook)
where real-time notifications are shown according to each action performed.
Also, an email should be sent to that user.

Note - (YOU CAN USE ANY DJANGO LIBRARY EXCEPT DJANGO CHANNELS)

**this is the question that I want to solve. please help me.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Firebase Cloud Messaging service. There a lot of packages that work with this service. I recommend you to use `fcm-django` package for simplicity.